# Is it possible to use columns in a Wordpress page without resorting to HTML <table>?

Tags: html, wordpress, layout

I have almost completed a relatively simple Wordpress.com site on which the site sponsor has now requested the ability to set text/data on a particular page in columns: firstly to display rows of data consisting of left-aligned photograph / right-column of profile, and secondly to display a large number of embedded document links in, say, 3 columns of 10 links.

Although this is a nice idea, I don't think Wordpress.com allows for such layout, certainly not under a non-premium plan, and that it can only be achieved by using manually-inserted borderless HTML: am I right ?

Comment: There are numerous "column" plugins available for WordPress - do a web search and try any of the rated plugins. They will give you the ability to use different width columns and use shortcodes to create the columns you require. P.s. the plugins use DIV tags (not HTML "table") and use percentages to create responsive layouts.

Comment: Thanks, Chris; I am continuing plugin my search as I write, but nearly all of what I'm turning up at the moment is geared towards the self-hosted / Wordpress.org community. I'm also trawling the Wordpress.com support fora. I suspect I might have to upgrade to a Premium plan and attempt this via CSS customisation.